# Do templates shorten the size of source or binary or both

Tags: c++

I read that templates are complied into different entities so does that mean the binary size will be same as we have complied it using different functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They should shorten the source size (if they are reused) but not the binary size (the template is compiled for each different instantiation).

This differs from Java generics, where there is a full type erasure (generics only serve as a compile time verification of types) or C#, where generics are compiled into specific binaries that can be directly reused without having to recompile and generate more code.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that for each type you instantiate with a template the complier produces the relevant class to match that type - so if you use `List<int>`, `List<foo>` and `List<float>` there will effectively be three *different* `List` classes in your complied binary.

*Edit:*
What I didn't explicitly state was that I'm inferring that merging several classes in to a single template will (probably) not reduce the size of your binary, but should reduce the size of your source.

Comment: Your understanding is good, and also note that (unless you manually instantiate the class) only those methods that are actually used will be compiled. I did not add that to my answer as linkers can remove unused code from the binary, so a similar space optimization is available for non-templated code and that does not make a difference. +1

Answer (score 2):

It depends ... If you were going to implement for each type a separate class then source code size will decrease.

As of for binary most probably you will not see any significant difference, because if you were going to implement separate class for each type and you didn't because you have used templates it doesn't mean that binary size will decrease, because that code will be generated by compiler (for the instantiations), so you must not have any significant difference because "*code is the same*".

Answer (score 0):

The binary size depends on your compiler and the optimasations the compiler will perform to reduce the code size by elimnating redandant code.

Modern compilers are able to detect redundant code, so the binary size will not increase dramaticly by using templates.

Comment: I doubt that the compiler can do anything more with templates than with non-templated functions. Templates have external linkage, so they cannot be removed from the object file, and any technique that it can use to reduce the internal code of the template will also be used for non-templated code.

Answer (score 0):

Templates will definitely be a way to write more generic and shorter code. Instead of writing your function 
`blah` n times to deal with different types of parameters, you write it once with a generic type for the parameter.

Regarding the binary size, code will be generated for the instantiations you make of the template, that is, when you specify a type. I don't see how it would shorten binary sizes.